# Error on Omines Datatable when builden a Query in CreateAdapter

Tags: orm, datatables, adapter

On building a data collection in omines datatable in symfony 4.2 and using QueryBuilder

And I have this

```
function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
    $builder
        ->distinct()
        ->select('m, b, v, m.lfd')
        ->from(Meldung::class, 'm')
        ->leftJoin('m.lastUser', 'b')
        ->leftJoin('m.process', 'v')
        ->leftJoin('m.messageType', 't');           
}
```

I got this error message from symfony:

Cannot read property "id" from an array. Maybe you intended to write the property path as "[id]" instead.

This error message comes when I add m.lfd (or some other specific field) in the select list

I don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the **hydrate** option to **Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY**:

```
        ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
            'hydrate' => \Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY,
            'entity' => Meldung::class,
            'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
                $builder
                    ->distinct()
                    ->select('m, b, v, m.lfd')
                    ->from(Meldung::class, 'm')
                    ->leftJoin('m.lastUser', 'b')
                    ->leftJoin('m.process', 'v')
                    ->leftJoin('m.messageType', 't');
            }
        ])
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. but using this in omines datatable I've got only on resultset. So how to iterate through all and view them in datatable?